# How do I deploy to GAE from the Google Cloud Source Repository?

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

I'm considering moving my php Google App Engine project from Codenvy to the Google Source Repository and edit it there with the Source Editor, but I don't see how to cause it to deploy my project. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me, found through guesswork, trial, error, [Billy](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108223758/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457465/how-to-manually-deploy-direct-from-bitbucket-to-google-app-engine) and only a little docs.

I had set up GC Repositories to have [a repository which is a mirror to bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K4eA.png) , auto-named `default`. Note: `gcloud` for `default` below can fail to recognise a repository that got that name by *Rename*. And can [mistake a non-existent repository for an empty one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUX41.png).

## Recipe 1

UPDATE: Now, after updating the bitbucket source, the deployed app does not show the update, despite "Deployment successful"][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH4OK.png). I don't know why - perhaps [due to version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409981/application-does-not-update-after-deployment-in-app-engine/19413111#19413111). Workaround: Use Recipe 2.

1 Ensure project's app.yaml file contains `application:` and `version:` e.g. this

2 Go to [Google Cloud Patform](https://console.cloud.google.com)  and [select the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcU2n.png)

3 Click `Activate Google Cloud Shell` https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Mz9.png

4 In Google Cloud Shell, enter:

```
gcloud source repos clone default
appcfg.py update default
rm -rf default
```

This took ~20s to deploy and ~30s to complete.

## Recipe 2

1 Ensure project's app.yaml file *does not* contain `application:` or `version:` (else you'll get an [error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWVce.png)) e.g. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmbW1.png)

2 Go to [Google Cloud Patform](https://console.cloud.google.com) and [select the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcU2n.png)

3 Click Activate Google Cloud Shell https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Mz9.png

4 In Google Cloud Shell enter:

```
gcloud source repos clone default
gcloud --quiet app deploy default/app.yaml
rm -rf default
```

Warning: This can [leave a previous version accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8IJl.png).

This took ~65s to complete.

Re timing, compare [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108223758/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457465/how-to-manually-deploy-direct-from-bitbucket-to-google-app-engine), taking ~20s . Timings are for a Hello World project.