# How can I deploy direct from Google Cloud Source Repository to Google App Engine?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

Google offers **git -> App Engine** and **git <-> Source Repository**, so presumably somewhere it offers **Source Repository -> App Engine**.

But I can't find where... even after twice reading all the Source Repository and App Engine docs I can find, inc. https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/ .

I'd guess the procedure could be [How to manually deploy direct from Bitbucket to Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457465/how-to-manually-deploy-direct-from-bitbucket-to-google-app-engine) modified to access the SR files. But I can find the SR files in the GCS VM.

Deleting all the $HOME folders I do find

[image]

... have no effect on the files shown at Source:

[image]

Baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ostensible solution (untested by me) here: https://web.archive.org/web/20161119132814/https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/10/introducing-Google-Cloud-Shels-new-code-editor.html

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this would be to clone the repository to your machine (or Cloud Shell), then use the App Engine deploy tool (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/getting-started/deploying-to-app-engine) to deploy your app.

e.g.

```
gcloud source repos clone $REPO
cd $REPO
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

Comment: The question asks for direct :-) Thanks anyway for an indirect option.

Comment: That didn't work until I'd made adjustments. Those and some more are in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171916/how-do-i-deploy-to-gae-from-the-google-cloud-source-repository/40499674#40499674 .