# Automate Github commit to Google AppEngine version

Tags: google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform

I have many versions of my AppEngine in Google GCP as shown below:

[image]

I want to create a new `dev` version to test some changes before deploying to live version. But I want this `dev` version to be connected to a Github repo and auto deployed whenever I commit anything to that repo.

Kindly if anyone knows the steps for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by following next steps:

1. [Create new repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories) in Cloud Source Repositories.
2. [Connect created repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories) with the one in GitHub
3. [Create automated builds](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds) using Build Triggers.

For a reference, you can check also following Stack Overflow thread: [Deploy to Google App Engine via a GitHub Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308888/deploy-to-google-app-engine-via-a-github-repo) .