# How to deploy from Google Source Repository or GitHub to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, github

Please forgive any naivety I may have here. I have 2 highly related questions:

1) As in my title, how do I deploy an app written for Google Cloud (complete with app.yaml) from Google Source Repository to Google App Engine (or failing that, from GitHub)

2) If I am finding it so hard to find an answer to this already when it feels like it should be an obvious solution, am I just looking at this completely the wrong way?

I found the following answer:

[How can I deploy direct from Google Cloud Source Repository to Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490073/how-can-i-deploy-direct-from-google-cloud-source-repository-to-google-app-engine)

Which doesn't seem to answer the question either, and it seems there was a 'push to deploy' feature in GitHub pushing straight to Google App Engine, that has mysteriously disappeared from the body of this blog post:

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/04/using-github-for-push-to-deploy.html

I'm really confused because it seems to me that it should be an obvious workflow to have an updated repo in GitHub, that you immediately want available in google's cloud (via Google App Engine) - am I crazy for wanting this? Should I be doing it some other way? Why would I want to download the repo to my local machine and then clone it to Google App Engine and deploy.. isn't that just unnecessary workflow?

Sorry I'm confused and will appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122249/google-cloud-how-to-deploy-mirrored-repository/42123320#42123320

Comment: I filed a feature request for this over 5 years ago in the gae issue tracker. Now maybe it's possible to configure travis-ci to deploy it for you, or a similar system. I don't know what gitlab can offer here but they state that they offer continuous integration similar to travis-ci.

Comment: I'm finding actually that once I have cloned the git from Google Cloud Repository (which is a constant mirror of the guthub repo), then all I need to type is:

`git pull`

to get the app to update its source code from the latest that is in the github master. I was thinking that I need the whole project redeployed whenever there is a code change, which is incorrect.

This leads me to think my question is actually how do I get the cloned repo to automatically pull from the master when there is an update.

Comment: Subsequent working: actually I'm wrong, pulling the git again does *not* update the source code. It seems I have to run `gcloud app deploy` after `git pull` to get the source code to update. Since the delopyment takes a few minutes, surely I can't have to do this everytime? I'm running it as a testing server - it would be much quicker to have a LAMP stack and just FTP file edits to the server! So confused :'(